# Customizing headers or signatures for new R scripts

Tags: r

I'm wondering if R Studio has user setting options that allow you to create a "running header" or "signature" for each new R script. For example, I would like to open up a new R script and have something like the following embedded in the new window:

```
###########################################################-
# Objective: 
# Author: 
# Date Modified:
###########################################################-
###### 1. PREAMBLE ######
```

Comment: A snippet or add-in is probably your best way to go here but if you transfer your workflow to Rmd you can setup your own templates that way, too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Perfect, thanks.